# How to make a vim variable determinable by bash?

Tags: bash, vim

I'm not sure how to word my question exactly...
I have the code

```
 if grep  "mynamefolder" /vol/Homefs/
then
  echo "yup"
else
  echo "nope"
fi
```

which gives me the output

`grep: /vol/Homefs/: Is a directory
nope`

The sh file containing the code and the directory I'm targeting are not in the same directory (if that makes sense).

I want to find the words `myfoldername` inside `/vol/Homefs/` without going through any subdirectories. Doing `grep -d skip`, which I hoped would "skip" subdirectories and focus only directories, just gives me `nope` even though the folder/file/word I'm testing it on does exist.

Edit: I forgot to mention that I would also like `mynamefolder` to be a variable that I can write in putty, something like
`./file spaing` and `spaing` being the replacement for `myfoldername`.

I'm not sure if I did good enough explaining, let me know!

Comment: Do you just want to know if `/vol/Homefs/mynamefolder` exists?

Comment: Pretty much, and also the edit I made just a few seconds ago

Comment: How does it relate to vim variables?

Comment: Like I said, I wasn't sure how exactly to word my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just want

```
if [ -e /vol/Homefs/"$1" ]; then
  echo yup
else
  echo nope
fi
```

The `[` command, with the `-e` operator, tests if the named file entry exists.

`vim` is not involved, and `grep` is not needed.

Comment: I just tested this and it worked, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

If you're insisting on using `grep`, you should know `grep` doesn't work on directories.  You can convert the directory listing to a string.

```
echo /vol/Homefs/* | grep mynamefolder
```